# Python (or maybe JavaScript / Ruby): open source projects that will give me a (bit) of hand-holding

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, open-source

Ive been roaming around the interwebs looking for my first open-source project to contribute to - and most cool ones seem to be one-man bands on github, which I *could* fork - but wouldnt quite provide the code review etc. i think i want, so i can improve my python abilities.

Web.py, flask, celery, twisted etc look interesting - so far only the latter seems like a candidate for something I could properly contribute to, but even though im a decent(ish) python programmer, I think the whole event driven thing is probably too steep a learning curve for me to be able to contribute meaningfully for a while... so i'd probably like to start elsewhere.

Any suggestions?

btw. yes, there is a duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117561/what-are-good-open-source-projects-in-python-for-which-i-can-be-a-contributor - but it is two years old, I think it is fair to assume new stuff / projects will have emerged in the interim.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to choose one of the libs you often use and try to improve it for yourself or fix something you don't like about it. IMHO, recipe of the best code contribution is your own demands and interest, not because somebody persuaded you.

Comment: why do you feel you can't contribute to celery? I would be very happy if you did, and I'm willing to answer any questions necessary for you to get started!

Comment: sweet - well you'll be hearing from me in that case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look and see if you find [RCTK](http://rctk.googlecode.com/) interesting to contribute to. I'm trying to be as pythonic as possible, it actually supports python 3 if you find that interesting, and even writing demo applications is considered very useful.

I (the head developer) currently already have two contributes whose code I review. This seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the google summer of code proposals is a possibility -- not all the projects have been picked by students, and the organizations probably still would welcome anyone willing to work on them. Participating in gsoc is another option, of course!